# Smooth Scroll with Anchor on URL

Tags: javascript, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to use Smooth Scroll on my site, but I need the anchor id on URL, to give the funcion of browser Back Button. The problem is: I need the #anchor to show up before 400 ms, but I don't know how can I call that variable in my script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var $target = $(this.hash);
      $target = $target.length && $target
      || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if ($target.length) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().left;
        $('html,body')
        .animate({scrollLeft: targetOffset}, 400);
 var timer = setTimeout(function() {  
        window.location.href = '#[anchor]';
   }, 400);
       return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The `window.location.href = '#[anchor]';` change the url but not with the anchor name. How can I change that?

Comment: what is the name of the anchor?

Comment: Unfortunately is not just one anchor, the problem is that I need the page anchor every time I scroll between then.

Comment: I looked at my code where I do something the same and adjusted your code to implement it, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor is stored in the `hash` variable, see the example and check the comments:

```
if (target.length) {

    var _this = this; // first save the reference to 'this'

    var targetOffset = $target.offset().left;
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: targetOffset}, 400);
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {  
        window.location.href = _this.hash; // '_this.hash' contains the anchor
    }, 400);
    return false;
```

You can also use [window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) like this:

```
window.location.hash = _this.hash;
```